# How can I add next month buttons to my calendar in PHP?

Tags: php, calendar

I'm making a calendar in PHP for my project. I have the styling for the calendar and the page for the current month but I cannot work out how to add a "Next Month" button.

Below i have included the PHP code that I currently have.

```
<?php 
function build_calendar($month, $year, $conn) {
    //array for names of all days
    $days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thurdsday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');

    //first day of the month
    $day1 = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    //the number of the days in the month
    $numberDays = date('t', $day1);

    //info of the first day of this month
    $dateComponents = getdate($day1);

    //name of the month 
    $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

    //index value 0-6 of thr first day of the month
        $weekday = $dateComponents['wday'];

    //current date 
    $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');

    //create the html table
    $calendar = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar.="<Center><h2>$monthName $year</h2>";

    $calendar.="<tr>";
    //calendar headers
    foreach($days as $day){
        $calendar.="<th class='header'>$day</th>";
    }
    $calendar.= "</tr><tr>";
    //must only be 7 columns in the table
    if($weekday > 0){
        for($k=0;$k<$weekday;$k++){
            $calendar.="<td></td>";
        }
    }
    //day counter
    $currentDay = 1;
    //get the month number
    $month = str_pad($month,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    while($currentDay<=$numberDays){

        //if seven columns reached, start a new row
        if($weekday == 7){
            $weekday = 0;
            $calendar.="</tr><tr>";
        }
        $currentDayRel = str_pad($currentDay,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";


        $dayName = strtolower(date('I', strtotime($date)));
        $today = $date==date('Y-m-d')?"today":"";
        if($date<date('Y-m-d')){
            $calendar.="<td><h4>$currentDay</h4><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>N/A</button>";
        }else if($weekday == 0 or $weekday == 6){
            $calendar.="<td><h4>$currentDay</h4><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>N/A</button>";
        }else if(in_array($date, $bookings)){
            $calendar.="<td><h4>$currentDay</h4><button class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Limited Spaces</button>";
        }else{
            $calendar.="<td class='$today'><h4>$currentDay</h4><a href='book.php?date=".$date."'class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Book</a>";
        }


        $calendar.="</td>";
        //increment the counters
        $currentDay++;
        $weekday++;
    }
    //row of the last week in the month
    if($weekday!=7){
        $remainingDays = 7-$weekday;
        for($i=0;$i<$remainingDays;$i++){
            $calendar.="<td></td>";
        }
    }
    $calendar.="</tr>";
    $calendar.="</table>";

    echo $calendar; 
}   
?>
```

I am fairly new to PHP so i can't seem to work this problem out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good code layout and indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I've seen this project on stackoverflow before lol. Since it is clearly an educational project, what have you tried? Stackoverflow is not here to do your projects for you.